# Insides of eyelids and light

Tags: optics, vision

People commonly see the insides of their eyelids and see a little amount of light and no amount of light of the insides of their eyelids depending on what environment they're in, What's the difference of seeing the amount of light of the insides of their eyelids?

Comment: note that when near a nuclear detonation, you can see the bones in your hands that are covering your closed eyes: flesh is translucent.

Comment: You can't see the bones from your hands covering your closed eyes and flesh is not 100% opaque.

Comment: the people there said they could, and that wasn't even line-of-sight.

Comment: What?, when people are not facing the light, they see no amount of light.

Comment: Buildings reflect a lot of light.

Comment: Because they are inanimate objects, duh.

Comment: It means the light is coming from all directions, and you can't hide from it, and is so bright, you can't block it. This is from reports of people present at the time.

Comment: Okay, but their buildings, not humans, eyelids are pretty thin and protons don't detect light when people's eyes are closed.

Comment: FYI, I am talking about accounts from people at Hiroshima, in which case there was a large ball in the hundred's of thousands of Kelvin nearby, flooding everything with blinding light. That fact that lived to tell their story is because they weren't line-of-sight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your eyelids are partially transparent to light. In the presence of a strong light source, even with eyes closed some light will make it through. Usually it will be reddish after passing through the skin filled with blood vessels.

You may also see greenish, yellowish, magenta, or purplish images that fade after closing your eyes. These are called after-images and are the result of the chemicals in your retina resetting themselves after light is removed. They typically consist of cyan, magenta, and yellow which are are opposite colors of your cone receptors: red, green, and blue.

Comment: When you're not facing the light, you see no amount of light and you see a dark color, I usually see white after-images when looking at the screen on my laptop. Eyelids aren't 100% opaque, but not partially transparent.